# Animated random walk in 3D [Python]

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm coding a function which would animate a random walk in 3D but unfortunately the code isn't working. Where is a plot, no errors occur but nothing happens. I'm using `%matplotlib tk`.
There is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def path_generator(steps, step):
    path = np.empty((3, steps))
    for i in range(1, steps):
        x_ran, y_ran, z_ran = np.random.rand(3)
        sgnX = (x_ran - 0.5)/abs(x_ran - 0.5)
        sgnY = (y_ran - 0.5)/abs(y_ran - 0.5)
        sgnZ = (z_ran - 0.5)/abs(z_ran - 0.5)
        dis = np.array([step*sgnX, step*sgnY, step*sgnZ])
        path[:, i] = path[:, i - 1] + dis

    return path

def animate(i):
    global particles, trajectories
    for trajectory, particle in zip(trajectories, particles):

    trajectory.set_data(particle[0:2, :i])

    trajectory.set_3d_properties(particle[2, :i])  

return trajectories

def random_walk_3D_animated(n, traj = 1):

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)

    particles = [path_generator(n, 1) for i in range(traj)]

    trajectories = [ax.plot(particle[0, 0:1], particle[1, 0:1], particle[2, 
                    0:1])[0] for particle in particles]

    ax.set_xlim3d([-100, 100])
    ax.set_ylim3d([-100, 100])
    ax.set_zlim3d([-100, 100])

    animacion = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 1000, interval=50, 
                                        blit=False)

    plt.show()
```

What is strange, the code do work when there is no function `random_walk_3D_animated(n, traj = 1)` and the values `n` and `traj` are given. And sometimes the code doesn't start the random walks from `(0,0,0)`. I wonder why.

Comment: I already commented below your last question that you need to return a reference to the animation. Will you now continue asking "the random walk" question forever?

Comment: I know I have been asking this questiong for a while and I'm really sorry for that. I made a big progress since the last one however :) Unfortunately I don't know how to return a reference to the animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The start position will be the content of the emty array. This may be any value so it is not really useful here. Instead initialize `path` with zeros.
2. You need to return a reference to the animation. From the [animation documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#animation): "[..] it is critical to keep a reference to the instance object."

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def path_generator(steps, step):
    path = np.zeros((3, steps))
    for i in range(1, steps):
        x_ran, y_ran, z_ran = np.random.rand(3)
        sgnX = (x_ran - 0.5)/abs(x_ran - 0.5)
        sgnY = (y_ran - 0.5)/abs(y_ran - 0.5)
        sgnZ = (z_ran - 0.5)/abs(z_ran - 0.5)
        dis = np.array([step*sgnX, step*sgnY, step*sgnZ])
        path[:, i] = path[:, i - 1] + dis

    return path

def animate(i):
    global particles, trajectories
    for trajectory, particle in zip(trajectories, particles):
        trajectory.set_data(particle[0:2, :i])
        trajectory.set_3d_properties(particle[2, :i])  

def random_walk_3D_animated(n, traj = 1):
    global particles, trajectories
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)

    particles = [path_generator(n, 1) for i in range(traj)]
    trajectories = [ax.plot(particle[0, 0:1], particle[1, 0:1], particle[2, 
                    0:1])[0] for particle in particles]
    ax.set_xlim3d([-100, 100])
    ax.set_ylim3d([-100, 100])
    ax.set_zlim3d([-100, 100])

    animacion = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 1000, interval=50, 
                                        blit=False)
    return animacion

ani = random_walk_3D_animated(100, traj = 1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I'm done. Once again - I'm really sorry but that's my first attempt to animate a plot.